# SonarQube doesn't support lombok

Tags: sonarqube, lombok

I want to reduce the class complexity of my overall project, so I am using [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/). Problem is, using SonarQube at the same time brings an increase in major issues (Remove this unused ... private field) and I don't know how to fix this.

Is there a way to fix this / reducing those major issues ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: We could use more informations about what kind of issues, on what piece of code. At this point, we cannot do much for you.

Comment: Yes, that issue is because when using Lombok, we will remove all getters, setters, equals, toString,... So SonarQube says "This private fields will never be used", that's the problem!